# Should i use my own properties inside a Class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I'm thinking about using properties of a class inside the same class. But i'm unsure which way is better.
In the first example the properties are only for the "outside". Inside i use own attributes and methods.
In the second example i use the properties inside, too.

What is the better way ?

this?

```
class Temperature_Calc_dont_use_properties_inside:
    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.__temperature = temperatur
        return

    @property
    def actual_temperature(self):
        return self.__temperature

    @property
    def actual_temperature_farenheit(self):
        return self.get_farenheit()

    def get_farenheit(self):
        farenheit = (self.__temperature * 1.8) + 32
        return farenheit

    def calculate_something(self):
        result = self.get_farenheit() * 99
        return result
```

or this ?

```
class Temperature_Calc_use_properties_inside:
    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.__temperature = temperatur
        return

    @property
    def actual_temperature(self):
        return self.__temperature

    @property
    def actual_temperature_farenheit(self):
        return (self.actual_temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def calculate_something(self):
        result = self.actual_temperature_farenheit * 99
        return result
```

Comment: You should make sure that your properties add some value to your code.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably be marked as opinion-based question, but I'd go with the second solution. It is clear enough what that property does without need to complicate code with additional method.